# Single char permutations

Tags: list, haskell, permutation

I've been experimenting with Haskell for quite a while now, and I've found an interesting problem:

I've got to generate all permutations of a string in a **very particular** way:

Let's say I've got this string:

```
let input = "_h_i_"
```

I want to get all the permutations of underscores in `input` keeping the actual order of the other chars, like this:

```
let results = ["hi___", "h_i__", "h__i_", "h___i", "_hi__", "_h_i_", "_h__i", "__hi_", "__h_i", "___hi"]
```

and I've no idea on how to do that.

Comment: You could approach this by stripping the string by all its underscores, remembering the count `n` of underscores and then introducing all permutations of `n` underscores to the stripped string...

Comment: do you mean the permutations of possible positions of underscores in the word?

Comment: It's a lot easier to make a function like `allUnderscorePlacements :: Int -> String -> [String]`, where your example would be called `allUnderscorePlacements 3 "hi"`.  Use another function to turn `"_h_i_"` into the `3` and `"hi"` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
so :: String -> [String]
so = takeWhile' notDone . iterate shift . preproccess
  where    
    preproccess xs = (replicate (uCount xs) '_') ++ (letters xs)
    uCount = length . filter (=='_')
    letters = filter (/='_')
    notDone = not . and . map (== '_') . dropWhile (/='_')

takeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile' _ [] = []
takeWhile' f (x:xs) 
  | f x = x:(takeWhile' f xs)
  | otherwise = [x]

shift :: String -> String
shift [] = []
shift (x:xs)
  | x /= '_' = roll lead [] rest
  | otherwise = roll [] [] (x:xs)
  where     
    (lead,rest) = span (/='_') (x:xs)
    roll _ acc [] = acc
    roll _ acc [a] = acc++[a]
    roll ins acc (a:b:bs)
      | (a == '_') && (b /= '_') = acc++ins++(b:a:bs)
      | otherwise = roll ins (acc++[a]) (b:bs)
```

Probably not the prettiest code, but it seems to work.  The algorithm is essentially the same as the one you used to do it by hand, except in reverse.

`shift` works by rolling across the string and shifting the leftmost non-underscore character to the left. This is repeated until all non-underscore characters are on the left.

The preprocess is just to get all of the underscores on he left and all other characters on the right.

Answer (score 1):

One way to perform this is to generate all permutations but only keep those that retain the order of non-underscore characters.

```haskell
import Data.List

orderedPermutationsOf :: Char -> String -> [String]
orderedPermutationsOf c s =
  let except = filter (/= c)
  in nub $ filter (\x -> except s == except x) $ permutations s
```

It isn't very performant, but it gets the job done.

Comment: nice! but I need it to be *somewhat* fast

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution

```
u='_'

perms :: String -> Int -> [String]
perms x 0 = [x]
perms [x] n = rotations $ x: (replicate n u)
perms (x:xs) n = (map (x:) $ perms xs n) ++ if(x/=u) then perms (u:x:xs) (n-1) else []

rotate xs n = zipWith const (drop n (cycle xs)) xs
rotations x = map (rotate x) [1..length x]
```

I changed the input signature, use as

```
> perms "hi" 3
["h___i","h__i_","h_i__","hi___","_h__i","_h_i_","_hi__","__h_i","__hi_","___hi"]
```

I think there is a simpler solution hiding there but don't have enough time now.